# Strain gauge connected to op-amp: finding its range of measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

Given [here](https://www.multisim.com/content/Amiz7pPtAyFZr47mRyCTZj/strain-gauge-and-op-amp/open/) (copied below) is a quarter strain gauge with R1 = R2 = R3 = R4 = R = 120 Ω  and R4 = R + ΔR as the variable resistance, where the change ΔR is caused due to mechanical forces applied to the test structure.

[image: schematic]

Given V1 = v<sub>s</sub> = 1.35 V, R5 = R7 = ℜ = 10 kΩ and R6 = R8 = 10ℜ = 100 kΩ; the op-amp is supposed to be ideal with input impedance  Z<sub>i</sub> → ∞ and output impedance Z<sub>o</sub> = 0, open loop gain A = 10<sup>5</sup>, and I = [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6] represents mesh current vector, taken clockwise. Then the mesh equations are:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}2R+\Delta R & 0 & 0 & -R-ΔR & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 2R & -R & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & -R & Z_i+11ℜ+R & -10ℜ & -Z_i-10ℜ & 0\\\ -R-ΔR & 0 & -10ℜ & 11ℜ+R+\Delta R & 10ℜ & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & (A-1)Z_i-10ℜ & 10ℜ & Z_o+20ℜ+(A-1)Z_i & -Z_o\\\ 0 & 0& -AZ_i & 0 & AZ_i-Z_o & R_L+Z_o\end{pmatrix}I=\begin{pmatrix} -v_s\\\ v_s \\\ 0\\\ 0 \\\ 0 \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Retaining the dominating terms only in the impedance matrix, and neglecting the term Z<sub>o</sub>, it becomes:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}2R+\Delta R & 0 & 0 & -R-ΔR & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 2R & -R & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & -R & Z_i & -10ℜ & -Z_i & 0\\\ -R-ΔR & 0 & -10ℜ & 11ℜ & 10ℜ & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & (A-1)Z_i & 10ℜ & (A-1)Z_i & 0\\\ 0 & 0& -AZ_i & 0 & AZ_i & R_L\end{pmatrix}I=\begin{pmatrix} -v_s\\\ v_s \\\ 0\\\ 0 \\\ 0 \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Solving in maxima for i6 in the limit Z<sub>i</sub> → ∞,
$$
\text{o/p voltage}, v_o=i_6R_L|_{Z_i \to \infty} = Av_s \frac {(R+ΔR)^2 + 9ℜ\Delta R-2ℜR}{(R+ΔR)^2 -11ℜ\Delta R-22ℜR}
$$
Now it has been asked if the smallest o/p voltage detected is 100 μV, what is the minimum value of R that can be measured? Putting
$$v_o = 100 \mu\text{V} \rightarrow \Delta R = 24.3 \Omega,R_{\text{min}} = R-\Delta R =95.7 \Omega $$

This is absurd, because the actual simulation gives a value of ΔR = 3.6 mΩ for v<sub>o</sub> = 100 μV. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does your question boil-down to needing someone to check your maths (rather than wanting a proper engineering answer)? If so, there is math.SE.

Comment: @Andy aka, I want a proper engineering answer , either my way or any other, not just checking the maths

Comment: The simulation method is a proper engineering answer.

Comment: If you have an ideal op-amp with a gain of 10 leave it out of the equations, it doesn't change anything.   
You then have a 120 ohm bridge with a 10k load at each arm and you have a 10uV differential. Restart from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated with Maple sheet. Confirmed your sensitivity 3.6 mOhm for 100uV.

[image]

Comment: what a silly mistake I did!! I was forming mesh equations over a non-planar circuit, which would never work. Tysm!

Comment: No worries ... It was a good question.